# How to change keyboard layout for an specific virtual terminal?

Tags: console, keyboard-layout

I know that "loadkeys" is used to change keymaps on the console but when it changes the keymap settings it changes it for all virtual terminals. I looked at the man page and it mentions a "--console" option but when I specify a VT through this option it doesn't make any difference.

I'm using Debian 8 (jessie).

Is it possible to change the keyboard map just for the VT that I'm using right now and leaving all other VT with the keymap they have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the manual page for [`loadkeys`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/loadkeys.1.html) says you cannot, in the [*WARNING*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/loadkeys.1.html#WARNING) section:

> Note that anyone having read access to `/dev/console` can run `loadkeys`
>   and thus change the keyboard layout, possibly making it unusable.
>   Note that the keyboard translation table is *common for all* the
>   virtual consoles, so any changes to the keyboard bindings affect all
>   the virtual consoles simultaneously.
>
> Note that because the changes affect all the virtual consoles, they
>   also outlive your session. This means that even at the login prompt
>   the key bindings may not be what the user expects.

The date for the manpage (6 Feb 1994) is a long time ago.  It may have been that the author of the program thought that some future version of Linux would support independent keymaps for the different virtual terminals.  That was a while ago, and the Linux console has not been the focus of development for almost as long as that.